# data table out of format in vf page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I am getting the below unformated table output. Can anyone please help me out in this how to correct it.

[image]

----------------------------->

### VF Page

```
<apex:form id="theForm" >
<apex:sectionHeader title="AXA Task Activity Tracker Report" />
<apex:selectList label="Source" value="{!SelectedDept}" styleClass="form-control multiselect" multiselect="true" size="0"  title="Source" id="DPList"  style="margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:10px">
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}" reRender="theForm" status="actStatusId"/>
<apex:selectOptions value="{!AllDept}" ></apex:selectOptions> 
</apex:selectList>
<!--Display Data -->
<apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId" >
                        <apex:facet name="start" >
                            <apex:image url="{!$Resource.BusyCursor}" width="500" height="20"  style="float:left;margin-left: 350px"/>                   
                        </apex:facet>
</apex:actionStatus>

<table class="table table-bordered" >

 <thead>
 <tr>
        <th>Task Name</th>
        <th>Business Lead</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Status</th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!results}" var="f">
 <td>
  <apex:outputText value="{!f.Name}" />
 </td>
  <td>
  <apex:outputField value="{!f.Business_Lead__c}" />
 </td>
   <td>
  <apex:outputField value="{!f.Description__c}" />
 </td>
    <td>
  <apex:outputField value="{!f.Updates__c}" />
 </td> 
     <td>
  <apex:outputField value="{!f.Status__c}" />
 </td>     
</apex:repeat> 
 </tr>      

    </thead>           
</table>  
</apex:form>
```

-------------------------->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe reason that's happening is because of the wrong placement of the `<thead>` tag.

Your `<thead>` tag should end after you have defined your headers.

```
<thead>
   <tr>
        <th>Task Name</th>
        <th>Business Lead</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Status</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <apex:repeat value="{!results}" var="f">
    <tr> 
       <td>{!f.Name}</td>
       <td>{!f.otherFields}</td>
    </tr>
   </apex:repeat>
</tbody>
```

And the rest of the rows should be placed in `<tbody>` tag.

Comment: <table class="table table-bordered" >
 <thead>
 <tr>
        <th>Task Name</th>
        <th>Business Lead</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Status</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>   
 <tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!results}" var="f">
 <td>

  <apex:outputText value="{!f.Name}" />

  <apex:outputText value="{!f.Business_Lead__c}" />

  <apex:outputText value="{!f.Description__c}" />

  <apex:outputText value="{!f.Updates__c}" />
 
  <apex:outputText value="{!f.Status__c}" />

 </td>  

</apex:repeat>
  
 </tr>      
        
</table>
The output is still the same..

Comment: updated my code. You should place the `<tr>` tag inside the `<apex:repeat>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. One more question . How can make the columns as responsive?? Now the columns are not responsive according to the device..Please hep

Comment: You should post that as a separate question as you will get better answer. My suggestion is post is on stackoverflow. But this article ( https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php) should get you started. ALso check out the twitter bootstrap for responsive tables